# Forensics copy, dcfldd

Tags: forensics

`dcfldd` is often recommended in forensics to duplicate hard drives. One of the reasons `dcfldd` is preferred over `dd` is the on-the-fly hashing feature.

**Q:** can I really rely on this feature to ensure the integrity of my copy since the hashing is performed on data in memory and not the data written on disk?

Comment: From the [download page](http://dcfldd.sourceforge.net/): `Hashing on-the-fly - dcfldd can hash the input data as it is being transferred, helping to ensure data integrity.` They only claim that it helps, not guarantees.

Comment: So if i understand correctly after performing the copy, i must perform hashing on the image and compare it to the output given by the dcfldd utility to ensure its integrity?

Answer (score 1):

If you create and verify the hash, it will detect errors that occurred on the write option. As you point out, read errors can't be detected as they will have occurred before the hash.

According to the [ShoeStringForensics blog](https://shoestringforensics.wordpress.com/2009/09/12/imaging-using-dcfldd/), you can verify the copy with:

```
dcfldd if=/dev/sdb1 vf=/media/disk/test_image.dd verifylog=/media/disk/verifylog.txt
```

You should redo the copy if the hash check fails.

Comment: Thank you. 
I was thinking about doing something like this to duplicate the hard drive and check its integrity.
sudo dcfldd if=/dev/sdb of=usb.img bs=3M hash=sha256 hashlog=sha256.txt; sha256sum usb.img

Comment: That seems right